# What entities does the black field include in the memory allocation diagram of the Crome DevTools "Memory" tool

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm looking for a memory leak in a web application. I took a picture of the pile. Can you tell me what entities the black sector of the diagram includes?
[image]